# Is there a best practice to define long strings in JavaScript considering column width?

Tags: javascript, string

I sometimes run into situations where I would need a best practice to define a long string. I'm talking about something like this:

```
const text = 'This is indeed a very long string. Some might say that it is really, really long.'
```

My problem here is that the string is just too wide. If I would prefer a solution where the column width is considered. I would usually use one of two solutions:

**a.)**

```
const text = 'This is indeed a very long string. ' + 
  'Some might say that it is really, really long.'
```

The problem with this one is that it uses an unnecessary concatenation.

**b.)**

```
const text = `This is indeed a very long string.
Some might say that it is really, really long.`
```

And the problem with this one is that the resulting string will actually contain a new line, which might not be wanted in some situations.

I realize that this might be a question for opinionated answers, but I still feel like that I'm missing something, or that there is a better solution out there. Please show me if you have one!

Comment: "The problem with this one is that it uses an unnecessary concatenation." - **no it doesn't**: In pretty much every JavaScript engine today, concatenation of string literals happens during the JIT phase, so there is no runtime cost (Source: I used to work on the Chakra engine when I was at Microsoft).

Comment: https://github.com/airbnb/javascript#strings--line-length
here is what airbnb style guide says

Comment: Not to mention, if you run your JavaScript through a minifier, the string is unlikely to survive that process exactly as it is in your code.

Comment: There is no "best practice", and any answers to this question will be an opinion.

Comment: @Dai But JIT compilation happens at run time.

Comment: You can see the logic for the optimization of string concatenation for ChakraCore inside the `ConcatString` and `LiteralString` classes: https://github.com/microsoft/ChakraCore/blob/b9b758cbddef9a588dc2aec64283432b358f8bb9/lib/Runtime/Library/ConcatString.h

Comment: @xehpuk The kind of string concatenation that happens during the "compilation" step where conversion from actual JavaScript to the interpreted bytecode or the native JIT is not comparable to a runtime JavaScript `string` concatenation. It's like arguing against concatenating literals in C++ because the C++ compiler will have to perform the literal string `constexpr` concatenation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the string continuation character \ (single backslash) to do that.

```js
const longString = "This is a really really \
long string that should \
not be split in multiple lines."
console.log(longString)
```

See the [documentation](https://developer.cdn.mozilla.net/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) in the **Long literal strings** section for details.